# .hide() not working with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've been trying to make a picture disappear when I click a button, something that should be fairly easy but doesn't seem to be working :/

Here is the HTML:

```html
<img id="projectA" src="link"/>
            <img id="projectB" src="link"/>
            <img src="link" width="35" height="35"/>
            <br>
        <button onClick="luck()" type="submit">Click here to donate luck!</button>
        <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
   $('#projectA').hide();
  });
 });
 </script>
```

I haven't included the image links as they were fairly large.

Really not sure why this isn't working, any help would be much appreciated :]

Comment: Maybe some errors in console?

Comment: I can't see you referencing jQuery anywhere - add this library first in order to use it's functionality.

Comment: Heed Paradoxis' answer, but also keep in mind your button is a *submit* button -- it will reload the page unless you prevent the event's default behavior or return `false` from the handler.

Comment: Advice: When using jQuery, do not use attribute-based event handlers at all. Just use jQuery style event handler registration. Using `onclick=` etc is a maintenance nightmare as it separates the registration from the handler.

Comment: You code works fine. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rw1mmu2g/) May you have problems including jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Because button is of type submit that is creating problem try `e.preventDefault()` and remove `onClick="luck()"`from HTML because button click is handled by jquery itself :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();   // prevent form submitting
        $('#projectA').hide();
   });
});
```

OR take a simple button of `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`.

**Suggestion :-** Instead of taking **button** itself as selector in jquery try giving a **unique id** to button in HTML and then use that id in jquery selector.

Comment: This doesn't work either. I guess buttons hate me. I'll just code in another <div> Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @theWhiteRaven..strange this should work..just give a id to button and then give that id in jquery selector...or instead of submit take a simple button and check for any console errors..

Comment: Nope still not working. I've already tried most of this anyway @Kartikeya

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a non-existent function, which throws an error.

Remove `onClick="luck()"` from your button in the HTML, should do the trick.

Comment: How do you know `luck` doesn't exist? :)

Comment: Well in this context it doesn't exist, and since it is causing an error for theWhiteRavenit must mean the function is undefined ;)

Comment: My guess is that onclick is "stealing" the jquery event.

Comment: The real thing is that even if `luck` doesn't exist, jQuery handler would still do its job and hide an image. http://jsfiddle.net/1mx5qoz2/

Comment: Oh yeah that was something I tried to fix it with earlier, included that by accident. Removing doesn't help though :[

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the default behavior of the button.

```
       $(document).on('click','button',function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#projectA').hide();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <img id="projectA" src="link"/>
        <img id="projectB" src="link"/>
        <img src="link" width="35" height="35"/>
        <br>
       <div class="xxx">Click here to donate luck!</div>
       <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.xxx').click(function() {
        $('#projectA').hide();
       });
       });
       </script>
```

Comment: Please explain what you did and why it will fix the problem.

Comment: i dont use buttons on click events, just a div with a class name, then when the div is clicked the image with the specific id will be hidden

Comment: ...and this fixes it *because it bypasses the submit button behaviour completely*. I hope you realise your default practice will not allow the use of the keyboard on your websites :(

Answer (score -2):

Your problem is been solve in the following fiddle 
Try This fiddle by Clicking [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2hkjd225/)
it will demonstrate your solution

i have removed the onClick="luck()" on the button

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $('#projectA').hide();
    });
});
```

change the jquery code to this and your problem will be solved 
and then the submit button will perform its other function of submitting data

Comment: a) Post your code as well. b) explain what it fixes and *why* :)